# Is there a way to run Node.js with Bash commands in Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to learn Node.js. When I download Node.js for Windows, I get the command prompt version for Windows, and I am wondering if there is a way to get a UNIX environment for Node.js in Windows. Most of the tutorials I read and watched just skip over this and I can't find anything on this.

Also, I am having a problem changing hard drives in Node.js command prompt. When I try `cd f:myDir`, it prints the directory instead of switching to it.

Comment: `cd mydir` should work...

Comment: Try using `cd f:\mydir`, your demo there seems to be missing the backslash.

Comment: what do you mean node UNIX environment for node.js?

Comment: @Rayon It' doesn't work because my main drive is C:. I also tried "cd f:\mydir".

Comment: This is off-topic (as a software request), but you can just install [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and have fun.

Comment: simply install GIT to run the most common ones in cmd.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use Cygwin for a UNIX environment while using Node.js. Download Cygwin here: https://www.cygwin.com/

I didn't have to mess with Environment Variables.

Comment: If you meant that kind of environment you could also try mobaXterm.. Pretty good, also i believe windows 10 now has bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

As of the Summer 2016 update to Windows 10, [a Linux shell environment for Windows is available](http://www.zdnet.com/article/ubuntu-and-bash-arrive-on-windows-10/).

- Install Windows 10 version 14316 via Windows Update
- Go to Updates & Security > For Developers > Developer Mode
- Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > Windows Subsystem for Linux
- Restart
- Open the Start menu and search for *bash*

Comment: I don't have windows 10 and don't plan on updating. Good to know though, in case I do.